# What structure to generate reports using Jinja2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

I have some Python in Jupyter notebooks that creates pivot tables and some graphs from data. I now want to make PDF reports from this data and I'm looking at making HTML with Jinja2 and converting that to PDF.

I get that Jinja can have a base template and child templates that inherit from it. What I want is a base template that I can render that pulls HTML in from other files (so the base template doesn't get huge and I can debug smaller pieces).

What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Good evening,

In your case, what I would do is having a folder with your templates.

For example:

```
templates
|- base.html
|- my_template.html
|- another_template.html
```

### Include

A solution is to use `include`:

For example in your `base.html` you would have:

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
{% include ['my_template.html', 'another_template.html'] %}
</body>

</html>
```

Here we include the results of rendering `my_template.html` and `another_template.html` in your base.html template.

You will have to give to your render function all the parameters needed for all the HTML templates you want to render.

### Extends

With jinja2 you can also do what you want by using the `extends` capacity.

So let's say you have a template `base.html` of the type:

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
{% block core %}
{{ content }}
{% endblock %}

</body>

</html>
```

Here, we have a block named `core`.

You can then in another template extend the base template and replace the `core block` by something else, for example:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block core %}
<h1>Hello world</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately as you can see it means that if you want various HTML pieces you will have to do several `extends`.

You can have another template which is going to extend the previous template which extend the base one.

### Manual

The last solution which is in my opinion not recommended, but for the sake of it I will expose it here:

Have a base.html of the kind:

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
{% for html in list_html_to_render %}
{{ html }}
{% endfor %}
</body>

</html>
```

Then we don't use Jinja2 anymore in this case, but we render each html contained in the list_html_to_render passed to the render function.

I hope it helps.

Have a lovely day,

My best regards.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume - I was after an oversight of methods available here and confirmation that I'm not missing an obvious tool. I didn't think extends was the answer - includes it it.

Thanks again